# Magento 2 fresh install, admin page 404, css 404, js 404

Tags: magento2, admin, css, installation, 404

**Problem**

I've got a fresh install of magento 2 on ubuntu 20.04. I followed the install with composer [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html) on the mangento site. The installer completed with no complaints.

When I head over to my url I get a very sparse looking page with no css or js. A look in the console and network tab shows that the page is trying to load a number of assets but non are found.

```
GET https://website.com/pub/static/version1606418294/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/css/styles-m.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 58ms]
```

Looking into `pub/static` shows no directory called `version1606418294` perhaps this is a clue?

In addition to this heading over to the admin URI that was generated on installation gives a `404` for the whole page.

**Things I've Tried**

changing mode between development / production / default

deploying static content and flushing the cache

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magetno cache:flush
```

these are the current permissions

```
ls -la
total 1816
drwxrwxrwx 12 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 19:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root       4096 Nov 25 13:09 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data    188 Nov 26 18:21 .editorconfig
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data  11281 Nov 26 19:16 .htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data  11382 Nov 26 18:21 .htaccess.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   1519 Nov 26 18:21 .php_cs.dist
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data    101 Nov 26 18:21 .user.ini
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data 766543 Nov 26 18:21 CHANGELOG.md
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data    650 Nov 26 18:21 COPYING.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   2994 Nov 26 18:21 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data  10364 Nov 26 18:21 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data  10376 Nov 26 18:21 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data    700 Nov 26 18:21 SECURITY.md
drwxrwxrwx  4 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data    150 Nov 26 18:21 auth.json.sample
drwxrwxrwx  2 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   2634 Sep 23 20:01 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data 937015 Nov 26 18:21 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  4 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 dev
drwxrwsrwx  3 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 19:46 generated
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data     57 Nov 26 18:21 grunt-config.json.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   1370 Nov 26 18:21 index.php
drwxrwxrwx  4 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 lib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   5842 Nov 26 18:21 nginx.conf.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 magento www-data   1416 Nov 26 18:21 package.json.sample
drwxrwxrwx  2 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 phpserver
drwxrwxrwx  6 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 pub
drwxrwxrwx  7 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 setup
drwxrwsrwx  8 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 19:46 var
drwxrwsrwx 84 magento www-data   4096 Nov 26 18:21 vendor
```

rewrite module is enabled

```
a2enmod rewrite 
Module rewrite already enabled
```

here's a list of php modules while im at it

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

I read that changing `.htacces` in the projects root folder to affect symlinks might help, though neither of those two options seems to make any difference.

```
 13 ############################################                                                                      
 12 ## enable rewrites                                                                                                
 11                                                                                                                   
 10 #    Options +FollowSymLinks                                                                                      
  9 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch                                                                                     
  8                                                                                                                   
  7     RewriteEngine on
```

added the following to the bottom of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` as per magento's trouble shooting instructions. [here](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032994352) and [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite).

```
  4   <Directory /var/www/html>                                                                                       
  3           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                                                                          
  2           AllowOverride all                                                                                       
  1           Require all granted                                                                                     
48    </Directory>
```

I logged into mysql to see if magento is speaking to it but it seems to have made a whole bunch of tables so is probably ok?

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_magento                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_analytics_usage_version_log                    |
| admin_passwords                                      |
| admin_system_messages                                |
| admin_user                                           |
| admin_user_expiration                                |
| admin_user_session                                   |
| adminnotification_inbox     
.
.
.
| wishlist                                             |
| wishlist_item                                        |
| wishlist_item_option                                 |
| yotpo_order_status_history                           |
| yotpo_rich_snippets                                  |
| yotpo_sync                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
404 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I'm pretty much out of ideas, any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```